# call constructor reference in Kotlin

Tags: class, constructor, reference, kotlin

If I have a kotlin class like this :

```
data class  Anim (val name : String , var age : Int) {

constructor (a:Anim):this(a.name, a.age) {
}

constructor () :this("Dog") {  }

}
```

and I want Use constructor reference syntax ,

```
val a = ::Anim
```

then I got this error :

```
overload resolution ambiguity: 
public constructor PornModel() defined in com.ripple.PornModel
public constructor PornModel(a: PornModel) defined in com.ripple.PornModel
public constructor PornModel(name: String, country: String = ...) 
defined in com.ripple.PornModel
    val a = ::PornModel::( String,  String))
```

Please tell me how special the arguments

Any help is much appreciated! Al

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the error message Kotlin compiler does not know which `constructor` overload to pick. You have state the type of `a` explicitly e.g.:

```
val twoArgs: (String, Int) -> Anim = ::Anim
val oneArg: (Anim) -> Anim = ::Anim
val noArg: () -> Anim = ::Anim
```